# Data migration from couchbase to snowflake using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nosql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, couchbase

We have a requirement to do a poc for couchbase to snowflake data migration for 2 tables.

Please suggest and guide the approach.

I have good understanding of snowflake to expecting some code based for couchbase.